# Ignoring styles in Android

Tags: android

When applying styles, many of their parameters are ignored for some reason.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/regionColumn"
android:layout_width="170dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/regionHeader"
   style="@style/AppTheme.TableHeaderTextView"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:text="@string/region" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**For example**, when you add A TextView with a style to such a container, all padding and height are ignored.

**Style itself:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.TableTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">8pt</item>        
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
</style>
```

Why is this happening and how to solve this problem?

P.S. `TableHeaderTextView` is a column header. `TableTextView` is a regular table cell. Styles are not mixed up.

Comment: On which Android version are you testing?

Comment: your style name in text are not same in style. `TableHeaderTextView` and `TableTextView`

Comment: I'm testing in version 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

Indents must be specified in `LayoutParams`, otherwise they are ignored.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(5, 20, 20, 30);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your style in Styles.xml to `AppTheme.TableHeaderTextView` instead of `AppTheme.TableTextView` so it will look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.TableHeaderTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">8pt</item>        
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
</style>
```

And in `Styles.xml` where applicable use `app=""` instead of `android=""` for support of older versions. In current tags you don't need it to change by the way keep it as it is.

Comment: The mistake is not in the style name.